# How do I disable the GNOME desktop screen lock?

Tags: linux, configuration, desktop, gnome

How do I stop my GNOME desktop from locking the screen after a few minutes of idle time?

I already tried the official manual [at Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Desktop_Deployment_Guide/ch-ddg-lockdown.html) and tried to use `gconf-editor` and `gconftool-2` to set `/apps/panel/global/disable_log_out` and 
`/apps/panel/global/disable_lock_screen`. No luck.

Comment: If you are using a more current Linux running Gnome 3.x you'll want to be using `gsettings` rather than `gconftool-2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen saver can also lock the screen. Uncheck either 'Activate screensaver when computer is idle' or 'Lock screen when screensaver is active' or both in screensaver preferences. From commandline use `gnome-screensaver-preferences` or goto 'System->Preferences->Screensaver'.

*I think* the corresponding keys (for use with gconftool-2) are `/apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled` and `/apps/gnome-screensaver/lock_enabled`.

HTH

Answer (score 35):

On newer distributions of Linux, like Red Hat and CentOS 7, which run GNOME 3.x you'll want to disable this via the `gsettings` utility rather than `gconftool-2`. The default is 5 minutes before the system is considered idle. Setting the value to 0 disables this.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

This setting can also be made in the GUI `dconf-editor` from a logged in session of the user in question.

From the standard *System Tools* → *Settings* application, there is also a "Blank Screen" option in the power settings which may provide the same behavior as the gsettings command given previously. In my testing, setting the "Screen Lock" to "Off" in the privacy settings *DID NOT* disable the screen blanking after 5 minutes.

On a final note, you cannot run that gsettings command from a remote SSH session without getting errors. See the last reference link below.

It was quite a research effort to get this disabled on my virtual machine!

**References:**

- https://superuser.com/questions/727120/make-gnome-screen-lock-after-1-hour-not-15-minutes
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it
- https://superuser.com/questions/444896/gnome-settings-gsettings-vs-gconftool-2
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/323776/gsettings-not-working-over-ssh

Comment: Works great! On a side note, the value is in seconds, so resetting it to 5 minutes would be `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 300`

Comment: Is there a way to query the current value from the commandline too?

Comment: @shevy sorry I don't know offhand. I assume you tried `gsettings get ...` but other than that it's been awhile since I wrote this and I'm not a gesettings expert!

Comment: If you have Anaconda installed, make sure you use `/usr/bin/gsettings`, by default `gsettings` might run `/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/gsettings`.

Answer (score 7):

The gconf schema entry for this in `/etc/gconf/schemas/desktop_gnome_lockdown.schemas`, and it would seem to be that the following command would disable the GNOME desktop lock screen:

```
 gconftool-2 --set /schemas/desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_lock_screen --type boolean true
```

However, in reality it seems that no attention is paid to this parameter (in OL 7.2 anyways).

An effective, but clumsy, workaround is to navigate in the GUI to *Application* → *SystemTools* → *Settings* → *Power* and set PowerSaving Blank Screen to "Never".