# How to disable entirely the GNOME lock screen?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, gnome, lockscreen, gnome-shell

I've already followed the method to deactivate automatic screen lock as explained in [this article](https://www.fosslinux.com/3893/how-to-disable-screen-locking-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts.htm). However, when the screen turns off and I shake the mouse or press a key to wake it up, I'm still greeted with the lock screen (pictured below).

How can I disable entirely the Gnome lock screen, so that when I wake up the screen, it shows my desktop/apps and not this useless lock screen?

Please note that, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281077/how-do-i-disable-the-gnome-desktop-screen-lock), I still want the screen to turn off after a period of inactivity, but I don't want the lock screen to show up when I wake the screen up.

[image: GNOME lock screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found is to use a Gnome extension called [Disable Screen Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/).

Answer (score 5):

Please try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true`. It works on Arch, should work on Ubuntu. If you prefer GUI: dconf-editor > org > gnome > desktop > lockdown > …etc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I believe this is the same parameter as going into `Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try it or you "belive" only? Lockdowns are intented to be used in enterprise solutions so they are not visible in GUI.

Comment: Did /you/ try it? The purpose of "disable-lock-screen" is to "Prevent the user to lock his screen" [Description as shown in dconf-editor]. It removes the lock button from the top-right menu. It doesn't do what the OP asked, I tried...

Comment: This parameter is a key factor in lock screen. It also works with false, if you have problems enabling the lock mechanism (like me).